# Jacobians $\mathbb{F}_q$-isogenous to the direct square of an ordinary elliptic $\mathbb{F}_q$-curve of $j$-invariant $0$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, abelian-varieties, algebraic-surfaces

Consider an ordinary elliptic curve $E_b\!: y^2 = x^3 + b$, of $j$-invariant $0$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, such that $\sqrt{b} \not\in \mathbb{F}_q$.

> **Question.** What are some examples of hyperelliptic $\mathbb{F}_q$-curves $C$ of geometric genus $2$ whose Jacobians $J_C$
> are $\mathbb{F}_q$-isogenous to the direct square $E_b^2$?

Comment: $p=13,b=2, y^2 = x^6+4x^4+1$

Comment: Could you clarify ? Is your example generalized to infinitely many $p$ ?

Comment: Don't know. First example computer spat out.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: this answer originally ignored an important twist.

Take $C: y^2 = x^6 + b$.  There is a $(2,2)$-isogeny $J_C \to E_b\times E_{b^2}$ with kernel corresponding to the factorization $\{x^2 - \beta_1, x^2 - \beta_2, x^2 - \beta_3\}$ of $x^6 + b$, where the $\beta_i$ are the roots of $x^3 + b$.  While these $\beta_i$ may only be defined over some extension of $\mathbb{F}_q$, the set of factors is rational over $\mathbb{F}_q$, and therefore the isogeny is defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$.  The curve $E_{b^2}$ is a cubic twist of $E_b$, so if $b$ is a cube in $\mathbb{F}_q$ then you can compose to get an $\mathbb{F}_q$-isogeny to $E_b^2$.

I think a good reference for the isogeny construction (over number fields) is Section 3 of Howe, Leprevost, and Poonen's [Large torsion subgroups of split Jacobians of curves of genus two or three](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9809210).

Comment: hyperellcharpoly(Mod(1,13)*(x^6+2)) = x^4 + 12*x^3 + 61*x^2 + 156*x + 169
hyperellcharpoly(Mod(1,13)*(x^3+2))^2 = x^4 + 10*x^3 + 51*x^2 + 130*x + 169

Comment: Thanks @FelipeVoloch, I forgot about the possible twist!  The couple of examples I tried as a sanity check had b nonsquare but (unluckily) cubic.

Comment: Thanks @BenSmith. What about $(n,n)$-isogenies ($n > 2$) over $\mathbb{F}_q$ if $\sqrt{b}, \sqrt[3]{b} \not\in \mathbb{F}_q$ ?